# Terminal problem in visual studio code. I can't seem to run my code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal

when I try to run my code, this displays "The terminal process "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" terminated with exit code: 4294901760."

tried searching but not lucky enough to find solution even chatgpt couldn't give me potential solutions

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: related? https://github.com/DonJayamanne/vscode-python-manager/issues/54 are you using VS Code python manager?

Comment: Is it feasible to switch the terminal as CMD?

Comment: You did not specify what exactly you were doing to "run your code".  Also, I don't understand why you are tagging this _python_.

Answer (score 0):

Please use Python in VSCODE according to the [official document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial).

If the Powershell terminal is not available, try to switch to CMD.

[image]

[Introduction to the terminal.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/profiles)

*In addition, check whether it is available in the external terminal. If the external shell is not available, then this is not the problem of VSCODE.*